# Audio settings in Infinity G37 got disabled...No audio now

Tags: audio, infiniti

I was watching this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2D-Laz4E7tA

and tried it on my 2013 Infiniti-G37x car. And audio settings got disabled. I can see the CD/Aux input/ USB playing...but there is no sound now...

Has anybody faced such issue? If yes, what solution did work for you?

Comment: Looks like he factory reset it and then just looked around

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you try to retrace your steps by re-entering the diagnostic (or whatever it is) mode? Do a full factory reset and I'd bet you'd have success.

Comment: How to do factory reset? I cant see that option in settings...Can you please assist me?